# squid : org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 > was not provided by any .service

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I tried to install squid but when try to restart squid I have the following error

> Failed to restart squid.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1
>   was not provided by any .service files See system logs and 'systemctl
>   status squid.service' for details.

When I run `systemctl  status squid.service`
the result is

```
● squid.service - LSB: Squid HTTP Proxy version 3.x
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/squid; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-12-01 22:40:20 GMT; 48min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Main PID: 2090 (squid)
   CGroup: /system.slice/squid.service
           ├─2088 /usr/sbin/squid -YC -f /etc/squid/squid.conf
           ├─2090 (squid-1) -YC -f /etc/squid/squid.conf
           ├─2091 (logfile-daemon) /var/log/squid/access.log
           └─2092 (pinger)

Dec 01 22:40:18 myserver systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Squid HTTP Proxy version 3.x...
Dec 01 22:40:19 myserver squid[2088]: Squid Parent: will start 1 kids
Dec 01 22:40:19 myserver squid[2088]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 2090 started
Dec 01 22:40:19 myserver squid[2049]: Starting Squid HTTP Proxy: squid.
Dec 01 22:40:19 myserver systemd[1]: squid.service: PID file /var/run/squid.pid not readable (yet?)
Dec 01 22:40:19 myserver systemd[1]: squid.service: Supervising process 2090 which is not our child
Dec 01 22:40:20 myserver systemd[1]: Started LSB: Squid HTTP Proxy version 3.x.
Dec 01 22:40:20 myserver systemd[1]: squid.service: Supervising process 2090 which is not our child
```

anything I should do? just try to get a caching proxy setup but with limited knowledge...

```
Dec 01 22:40:19 myserver squid[2088]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 2090 started
Dec 01 22:40:19 myserver squid[2049]: Starting Squid HTTP Proxy: squid.
Dec 01 22:40:19 myserver systemd[1]: squid.service: PID file /var/run/squid.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Dec 01 22:40:19 myserver systemd[1]: squid.service: Supervising process 2090 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
Dec 01 22:40:20 myserver systemd[1]: Started LSB: Squid HTTP Proxy version 3.x.
Dec 01 22:40:20 myserver systemd[1]: squid.service: Supervising process 2090 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
Dec 01 23:39:05 myserver systemd[1]: squid.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Dec 01 23:39:07 myserver squid[2796]: Stopping Squid HTTP Proxy: squid.
Dec 01 23:39:07 myserver systemd[1]: squid.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 01 23:39:07 myserver systemd[1]: squid.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```